# Recycling bin not working for 1 drive on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

My recycling bin works fine on every drive but one. Before installing Windows 10, it worked fine.  If you right click the recycling bin and check if it's enabled, it is.  I gave it 200gb of space.  It doesn't matter how big of a file you try to delete.  A 0 byte file will still skip the recycling bin too.

[image: recycling bin properties for the problem drive]

[image: Deleting a small file]

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting your recycle bin and see if if works

Open Command Prompt as admin

Use command

```
rd /s /q C:\$Recycle.bin
```

Restart your computer then try and delete.

Comment: Great job answering this question. For the sake of improvement, it is always a good practice to include some reference to back up what you are saying will fix the problem.

Comment: Didn't work.  :(

Comment: So what is staying in the bin? I might have a great idea for you.

Comment: Anything deleted from the C drive, the R drive, and the V drive go to the bin.  Anything from the D drive skips it and is permanently deleted.

Comment: So could you explain a little more for me real quick. Are you not wanting to permanently delete things off D drive? And you are having files from your other drives stay when you try and delete them?

Comment: I want the files from the D drive to go to the recycling bin like the other drives.  When I delete files from other drives, they go to the recycling bin (this is what I want).

Comment: Hmmm try this I know it works for network drives    Right click on the a Personal Folder you don't use (e.g. Contacts) and choose Properties Find the Location tab Click Move... and set the new location to the root of the Drive I chose to not move existing files, there shouldn't be any anyway if you are not using them. Then try and delete something off that drive that permanently deleted and see if it moves it to the recycle bin.